# Does tkinter arrowshape require a tuple but stores as text?

Tags: python

I ran into a problem, since pulling *options["arrowshape"]* from the tkinter canvas resulted in a string "x y z", while setting the arrowshape in *create_line* will use a tuple [x,y,z] and not a string...
Is this correct in Python 2.7.10+

Comment: and what is your problem? (PS: `[x,y,z]` is a list not a tuple)

Comment: The problem is when retrieving the arrowshape data from the canvas it comes as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you create an arrow:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

can = Canvas(root, bg='white')
ar = can.create_line(5, 5, 100, 70, arrow='last', arrowshape='20 40 10')
can.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

You need to pass a string (or a list or a tuple) representing the shape of the arrow head. The first is the length, the last is the width, and the middle one relates to the amount of arc the arrow base has. You can play with it to get the taste.

You can designate the arrow shape also by

```
arrowshape=[20, 40, 10]
```

or

```
arrowshape=(20, 40, 10)
```

Comment: many thanks, I guess '20 40 10' is also the internal storage format for Tkinter